# Identify location of item in json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, indexing, dictionary-comprehension

Suppose I have the following json file. With `data1["tenants"][1]['name']`  I can select uniquename2. Is there a way to collect the '1' number by looping over the document?

```
{
    "tenants": [{
            "key": "identifier",
            "name": "uniquename",
            "image": "url",
            "match": [
                "identifier"
            ],
            "tags": [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "identifier",
            "name": "uniquename2",
            "image": "url",
            "match": [
                "identifier1",
                "identifier2"
            ],
            "tags": ["tag"]
        }
    ]
}
```

in short:  `data1["tenants"][1]['name']`= uniquename2  `data1["tenants"][0]['name']` = uniquename
How can I find out which number has which name. So if I have uniquename2 what number/index corresponds with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over the tenants to map the index to the name

```py
data = {
    "tenants": [{
            "key": "identifier",
            "name": "uniquename",
            "image": "url",
            "match": [
                "identifier"
            ],
            "tags": [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "identifier",
            "name": "uniquename2",
            "image": "url",
            "match": [
                "identifier1",
                "identifier2"
            ],
            "tags": ["tag"]
        }
    ]
}

for index, tenant in enumerate(data['tenants']):
    print(index, tenant['name'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0 uniquename
1 uniquename2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have turned your json into a dictionary already, this is how you can get the index of the firs ocurrence of a name in your list (This relies on the names actually being unique):

```
data = {
    "tenants": [{
            "key": "identifier",
            "name": "uniquename",
            "image": "url",
            "match": [
                "identifier"
            ],
            "tags": [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "identifier",
            "name": "uniquename2",
            "image": "url",
            "match": [
                "identifier1",
                "identifier2"
            ],
            "tags": ["tag"]
        }
    ]
}

def index_of(tenants, tenant_name):
    try:
        return tenants.index(
            next(
                tenant for tenant in tenants
                if tenant["name"] == tenant_name
            )
        )
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError(
            f"tenants list does not have tenant by name {tenant_name}."
        )

index_of(data["tenants"], "uniquename")  # 0
```